# How to view Cordova app in the browser with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I want to run my cordova app in the browser (not ripple emulator, but directly in the browser). One way of doing it I found on SO and it's simply set up IIS to the www folder. That works pretty fine, but I was wondering if it's possible to add a platform for the browser directly, so that it runs on F5. I am not very experienced at it, but I saw that e.g. in raw Ionic tools you can do "ionic serve" and it starts the web server and opens the browser. I suppose it runs node behind the scenes. It there an easy way to do that in Visual Studio either via node or IIs?

Comment: There's now an incipient *browser* platform, which the VS team promises to use in the near future, and Cordova has barely documented.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it is possible to add a "browser" environment in Visual Studio or even native Cordova. If you really need such a functionality, you could use IBM MobileFirst (which I would not recommend, as long as you are not using their server, too).

I personally have no need of F5 functionality in Visual Studio. Just save, go to the browser and press F5 there. For debugging, I am using Chrome with the developer tools.

BTW: I do not set up IIS to the www folder, but to the project folder. I am doing this, because I am using TypeScript as script language. The TypeScript files are beside the www folder. With my setup, Chrome is able to find the TypeScript source corresponding to the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

right click on the index.html file and then select **Open With..**-> add->
then select the browser from available programs and then click  on OK

Answer (score 1):

To open your cordova app in a browser while using Visual Studio 2015, I suggest using `Gulp` + `BrowserSync`:

Download `browser.sync` from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/).  The best way to download is to add it to package.json and automatically download it.

```
{
  "name": "content_md_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.10.0",
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

Add a gulp task to make launching easier. Create a gulpfile.js in the project root and add task. Example gulp task:

```
gulp.task('browser.sync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir:"./www/"
        }
    });
    // Note. you can add browserSync.reload to the tasks runner explorer array to make
    // all browsers reload after a build is complete.

});
```

Use Task Runner Explorer to launch the gulp task manually or automatically.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phonegap to test your app, you may type "phonegap serve" in command line NOTE: your cd has to be your application file path.
Then you may see the ip address:port number which can be used in browser,android and ios platform.

Example: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IIS node, for example http://localhost/cordovaApp, I use this approach in one of my project and it's really conveniently.